# jQuery animation on scaleY from 100 to 0 just set the value

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, transform

I have animation scaleY (added using css hooks) from 100 to 0 and it seams that it just set the value to 0, it don't work when I change it to 0.01 or 0.1, animation in oposite direction work fine.

I have code like this:

```
var back = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Card_back_06.svg';
var front = 'http://jcubic.pl/card_01.svg';

$(function() {
    $('.cards').on('click', '.card', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var img = $this.find('img');
        if (!img.is(':animated')) {
            img.css('scaleY', 100).animate({scaleY: 0.1}, function() {
                var file = $this.hasClass('back') ? front : back;
                img.attr('src', file).animate({
                    scaleY: 100
                }, function() {
                    $this.toggleClass('back front');
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mA9V/) (the code for the css hook is there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to set

```
.animate({scaleY: "0%"}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2mA9V/1/